# react native how to check FLog on android?

Tags: react-native

I want to see and check Logs on android native codes using terminal or something. How can I do?

I know `adb logcat -s ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V` but this is warnings on js side, not native side.

```
    try {
      updateInstanceHandle(resolveView(tag), instanceHandle);
    } catch (IllegalViewOperationException e) {
      FLog.e(TAG, "Unable to update properties for view tag " + tag, e); // <------- I want to see this !!!!!!
    }
```

I expect the logs on terminal but do not know how can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your own `LoggingDelegate` in your Application class using `FLog.setLoggingDelegate(YourCustomLogger())`

`YourCustomLogger` would implement `LoggingDelegate` and you could just use the normal `Log` for each override method. This will show all the RN logs for you.